# PagerSlidingTabStrip landscape mode padding fix

Tags: android, android-viewpager, landscape-portrait, pagerslidingtabstrip

I am using `PagerSlidingTabStrip` it's working fine in portrait mode but when I change it to landscape mode then they tabs don't cover all the screen real estate and stays left aligned.

How to make them evenly spaced?

[image: How to fix it?]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just go the library class i.e.  `PagerSlidingTabStrip` and change this line

```
private boolean shouldExpand = false;
```

to

```
private boolean shouldExpand = true;
```

Hope this helps.!

Answer (score 1):

```
<com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:background="@drawable/background_tabs"
        android:fillViewport="false"
        viewpager_:pstsIndicatorHeight="3dp"
        viewpager_:pstsShouldExpand="true" /> <---just make it true
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the width of your PagerSlidingTabStrip as match_parent. :)

```
<com.example.PagerSlidingTabStrip
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    **android:layout_width="match_parent"**
    android:layout_height="48dip"
    android:background="@drawable/background_tabs" />
```

Comment: it's horizontal scroll view so it will make no difference